Are finitely generated subgroups of $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{Q})$ virtually special?
This might be a silly question--but are there any examples of finitely generated subgroups of $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{Q})$ that are known to not be virtually special?

baumslag-solitar groups, right?

@MattZaremsky aren't these not $\mathbb{Q}$-linear? They're not generally residually finite are they?

That's right for things like BS(2,3), but the BS(1,n) actually are Q-linear. I can write something more helpful soon, when I'm not just on my phone.

Virtually special implies the much weaker PW property (acts properly on a CAT(0) cube complex). Plenty of f.g. Q-linear groups fail to have Property PW, e.g., those with Kazhdan's Property T (e.g. $\mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbf{Z})$), those with a distorted copy of $\mathbf{Z}$ such as $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z}[1/p])$ or (as already mentioned) solvable Baumslag-Solitar groups, non-abelien nilpotent torsion-free f.g. groups, etc.

@YCor Ah, I see. This isn't an area I'm terribly familiar with, but I was basically wondering if there are much stronger properties satisfied by f.g. subgroups of $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{Q})$ vs those of $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$.

Yes, there are, e.g., finite virtual cohomological dimension. But eventually this is not what you asked.

@YCor: what’s the argument that $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}[1/p])$ can’t act properly on a cube complex? I thought I recalled that it acts on a product of trees with finite stabilisers, but I don’t have my copy of Serre to hand to check.

@HJRW no, it acts properly cocompactly on the product of a tree (Bruhat-Tits of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Q}_p)$ and the hyperbolic plane (symmetric space of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{R})$). It doesn't have Property PW because it has a distorted infinite cyclic subgroup (inside a copy of a solvable Baumslag-Solitar group).

@YCor: I am puzzled, because a proper cocompact action on any CAT(0) space (not just a cube complex) should rule out having a solvable Baumslag--Solitar subgroup: cf. Corollary II.7.6 of Bridson--Haefliger. What am I missing?

@HJRW yes, sorry it's not cocompact (with a finite volume fundamental domain).

@YCor: thanks, that clarifies things. However, it calls into question the validity of the accepted answer. Virtually special is a little weaker than virtually compact special. Our discussion shows that translation-length considerations can only be used in the cocompact case. (Actually looking again at the accepted answer, perhaps this is what is intended...)

@HJRW I don't think it's a problem, because these groups just don't act properly at all on any CAT(0) cube complex. A group with a distorted $\mathbf{Z}$ cannot (no cocompactness or even finite-dimensionality assumption).

@YCor: OK, so what's the argument for that!? (This is what I was asking for originally...)

@HJRW This is originally due to Haglund with a geometric argument, and I proved it by elementary means (in terms of commensurating actions, so eventually it's a fact about abstract actions of $\mathbf{Z}$ on sets) in my FW paper (Corollary 6.A.3).

@HJRW, the proof by Haglund is Theorem 1.3 here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0705.3386

Slightly more detail though edit window expired: in any CAT(0) cube complex, up to cubically subdividing, non-elliptic isometries have combinatorial geodesic axes.  It follows easily that in an f.g. group acting on a CAT(0) cube complex (no restriction on dimension), distorted cyclic subgroups act elliptically.  (One subtlety is that when the dimension is infinite, one can't make this argument using CAT(0) translation lengths, since the CAT(0) and combinatorial metrics are no longer QI.)

The Baumslag-Solitar group $\mathrm{BS}(1,n)=\langle a,b \mid bab^{-1}=a^n\rangle$ embeds into $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$, generated by the matrices $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}n&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$. For $n\ge 2$ it is not virtually special, thanks to translation length considerations. Thus, I think the "easiest" example of a group you're looking for is $\mathrm{BS}(1,2)$.

For clarity, perhaps I'll spell out the argument. (I got a bit confused above -- see comments -- so perhaps others may too.) Virtually special means "virtually embeds in a RAAG", without any cocompactness assumption. RAAGs act properly and cocompactly on their Salvetti complexes. In a group acting properly and cocompactly on a CAT(0) space, every infinite-order element has a positive translation-length, and in particular is undistorted. But every finite-index subgroup of $BS(1,n)$ has a distorted infinite-cyclic subgroup.
